# MySQL is adding space in front of string

Tags: c#, php, mysql

So i'm using MySQL and C# in order to grab info from a database, but when i try to use that database info again in MySQL doesn't work because it seems to be adding a small space in front of the data. Let me show you what i mean.

php code that displays info on webpage

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nick = $_POST["myform_nick"];

$sql = "SELECT Lin FROM scores WHERE name='$nick'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $row["Lin"];
 }
```

}

Then in C# it is like this...

```
IEnumerator LeagueCheck(){
     var form = new WWWForm ();
     form.AddField( "myform_nick", formNick );
     WWW w = new WWW (URL, form);
     yield return w;
     if (w.error != null) {
         print(w.error); //if there is an error, tell us
     }
     else {
         print("League Check 1");
         LinII = w.text; //here we return the data our PHP told us
         print (w.text);
         Lin = LinI + LinII;
         w.Dispose(); //clear our form in game
         StartCoroutine (LeagueCheck2 ());
     }
 }
```

Inside LeagueCheck2 it uses LinII to grab another thing from the database but it can't find it because it comes back like this

" Dominators"

instead of like this

"Dominators"

So my question is how can i get it to remove that little space in front of Dominators.

What i've tried to fix this

```
using System;


LinII = String.Trim(w.text);

LinII = w.text;

LinII.Trim();

LinII.Replace(" ","");


void Timer(){

LinII.Trim();

}

//In the IEnumator LeagueCheck();

Lin = LinI + LinII;
w.Dispose(); //clear our form in game
Trimer();
StartCoroutine (LeagueCheck2 ());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if `w.text` and `LinII` are a string

```
if (w.error != null) {
     print(w.error); //if there is an error, tell us
 }
 else {
     print("League Check 1");
     LinII = w.text.Trim(); //here we return the data our PHP told us
     print (LinII );
     Lin = LinI + LinII;
     w.Dispose(); //clear our form in game
     StartCoroutine (LeagueCheck2 ());
 }
```

Comment: "WWW w = new WWW (URL, form);" I don't think w is a string but we shall find out